# ¿Cómo puedo capturar la salida de una función que hace ping a un servidor y mostrarla en un label de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, stdout, ping

Estoy realizando un programa que haga ping a varios servidores en una LAN. Ya tengo la función programada usando subprocess, estoy haciendo la GUI para que cuando se apriete un botón que representa un servidor se muestre en un label la información que muestra la consola.

Comment: Hola Klau, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so],  te recomiendo pasar por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Deberías agregar  tu código o al menos un [mcve] para poder dar respuestas orientadas a tu implementación concreta y no genéricas que luego tendrías que adaptar, de ser posible, a tu caso concreto.

Comment: Así mismo, es importante que especifiques si la actualización es en tiempo real (por ejemplo se hacen 10 pings, uno cada segundo y en el label cada segundo se actualiza la salida) o si en cambio se hacen los mismo pings uno cada segundo pero en el label solo aparece el resultado final una ve que el subproceso ha terminado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu función debería utilizar la palabra clave `return` que sirve para retornar un valor de una función.

```py
import os
def verificar_ping():
    hostname = "example.com"
    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
    # Verificar el EXIT_STATUS
    if response == 0:
        pingstatus = "Servidor activo"
    else:
        pingstatus = "Servidor inactivo"

    return pingstatus
```

La variable `response` guardará 0 si el ping es exitoso, 1 si no hay respuesta y 2 si hay otra falla [ver referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921398/exit-status-of-ping-command)

Finalmente almacenas el mensaje en la variable `pingstatus` y retornas ese valor en la función como sigue:

```py
mensaje = verificar_ping()
```

Con esto solo te quedará agregar la variable `mensaje` a tu label en `tkinter`.